# Node.js how to wait for a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have the following code which is contained within a much larger if statement block:

```
message.reply({ embeds: [multipleUsersEmbedFunction("Multiple Users Found", `The following users were found:\n${string}`, members)], components: [actionRow] }).then((embedMessage) => {
              const collector = embedMessage.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 5000 });
              collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
                console.log(i);
                return members[Number(i.customId)];
              });
            });
```

At the bottom of my code I have the following:
`return undefined;`, which is used by other if else statements which do not return anything.

However, this message collector (discord.js) of course should wait 5 seconds before returning undefined, however my code is still instantly returning undefined.

How would I circumvent this?

Comment: Why is the callback function `async`? It doesn't contain an `await` call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score -1):

If the reply that you are waiting is async, you must to considere using the `await` before the reply.
For example, if the reply use time or timer function, it's very posible that `await` is a solution for you.

Comment: if it uses promises, yes.  callbacks, no

Comment: `await`  is not a solution to this particular problem because the OP is using `collector.on(...)` which is NOT promise based and then trying to return a value from that event's callback which makes the return value go nowhere.